# corner ribbon for resposive image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a corner ribbon to sit over an image, on a responsive design site.  I have set up a fiddle page with the code I've got so far.  As you can see there, it seems to insert a top `margin` (the corner of the ribbon is not disappearing) and the `overflow` is not hidden.  Any ideas why?
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CaribbeanViking/L4kojc4k/)

```css
.ribbon-holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ribbon {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
  top: 52px;
  left: -32px;
  width: 145px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon-holder">
  <div class="ribbon ribbon-holder">Free Shipping!</div>

  <a href="http://www.somesite.com">
    <img src="http://www.adventurouskate.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/planes-black-shower-curtain.jpg" alt="Shower Curtin" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `position:relative` in the parent (`.ribbon-holder`) and `absolute` in the child (`.ribbon`)

```css
.ribbon-holder {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}
.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align: center;
  top: 32px;
  left: -32px;
  width: 145px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon-holder">
  <div class="ribbon ribbon-holder">Free Shipping!</div>
  <a href="http://www.somesite.com">
    <img src="http://www.adventurouskate.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/planes-black-shower-curtain.jpg" alt="Shower Curtin" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

html:

```
<div class="ribbon-holder" > 
    <a href="http://www.somesite.com" ><img itemprop="image" class="imageSize" src="http://www.adventurouskate.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/planes-black-shower-curtain.jpg" alt="Shower Curtin" /></a>
</div>
<div class="ribbon ribbon-holder">
    Free Shipping!
</div>
```

css:

```
.ribbon-holder{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ribbon{
    position: absolute;
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    text-align: center;
    top: 30px;
    left: -32px;
    width:145px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4kojc4k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes i made :

```
.ribbon-holder{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;// added by DamienBannerot
}
.ribbon{
    position: absolute;// added by DamienBannerot
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    text-align: center;
    top: 32px;// added by DamienBannerot
    left: -32px;// added by DamienBannerot
    width:145px;
}
```

fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/L4kojc4k/4/